# Convergence of the power of a matrix : a simpler proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, alternative-proof

Here is an exercise that I have been used in a oral exam (around 45 minutes) for undergrad students.

Let $A$ a $n\times n$ matrix with real coefficients such that
$$ A^T = 3A^2-A-I_n,$$
where $A^T$ is the transpose matrix of A and $I_n$ the identity matrix of size $n\times n$.

Here is what I have found: We have
$$ A = 3(A^T)^2-A^T-I_n,$$
and using that we have
$$ A = 3(3A^2-A-I_n)^2-(3A^2-A-I_n)-I_n.$$
Expanding the previous identity, we have
$$ 3I_n+6A-18 A^2-18 A^3+27 A^4=3 (3 A+1) (A-1) (3 A^2-1)=0.$$
So that $1$ is a possible eigenvalue of $A$, which can be difficult to deal with when we look at powers of a matrix. Consequently, I decide to write 
$$ X^n = (3 X+1) (X-1) (3 X^2-1)Q(X)+R(X),$$
withe $\deg R < 4$. One can find the exact formula for $R$ (which is ugly (in the basis $(1,X,X^2,X^3)$) see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolating+polynomial+%7B1,1%7D,%7B-1%2F3,%28-1%2F3%29%5En%7D,%7B1%2Fsqrt%283%29,%281%2Fsqrt%283%29%29%5En%7D,%7B-1%2Fsqrt%283%29,%28-1%2Fsqrt%283%29%29%5En%7D)) and see that $A^n = R(A)$ converge.

Is there an easiest way to solve this exercise?

Comment: Why do you consider only eigenvalue 1 and why do you say it is difficult to deal with ? The others are $-1/3$ and $\pm1/\sqrt{3}$. And you know that if the matrix is diagonalizable, you can write $A^n=1^nA_1+(-1/3)^nA_2+(1/\sqrt{3})^nA_3+(-1/\sqrt{3})^nA_4$ for certain  fixed matrices $A_1,... A_4$, which converges to $A_1$.

Comment: $A^T$ is a polynomial in $A$. Hence $A$ is normal. As all its possible eigenvalues are real, it must be diagonalisable over $\mathbb R$. As JeanMarie says, the powers of $A$ obviously converge.

Comment: @user1551 You are right ! I forgot this. It is may be useful to recall that "A normal" means "$AA^T=A^TA"$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Actually, no need to employ normality. As an answer below points out, the annihilating polynomial splits into distinct linear factors. Hence $A$ must be diagonalisable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already shown that $ (3A+1)(A-1)(3A^2-1) = 0$, so the only possible eigenvalues for $A$ are $-\frac{1}{3}$, $1$, and $\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. They all have their module $<1$, except $1$.

Since this polynomial cancels $A$ and it has simple roots, it implies that you can diagonalize $A$. If you do so, you will get a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal. This diagonal matrix easily converges, because $\lambda^n$ will converge to 0 if $\vert \lambda \vert <1$, and to 1 if $\lambda = 1$, when $n \rightarrow \infty$.